# Why .so files also work for windows?

Tags: windows, dll

I found this in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Isn't the `.so` files for linux?

Shouldn't it be `.dll` for windows?

Answer (score 8):

Two things I can think of here:

1. Apache is smart enough to use the platform-specific extension on other platforms and doesn't care *too* much about the .so.
2. DLLs can be named as you like, the extension can be arbitrary. You can name DLLs on Windows .so if you like.

**ETA:** As [mh](https://serverfault.com/users/5234/mh) mentions in a comment, it's actually both: Apache will load .dll files, even though .so is preferred on Windows systems ([Source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_so.html)). Of course, even if it's named .so, it's still a normal PE library.

Comment: Can it be proved?

Comment: +1: Apache, coming from a Unix background, shouldn't place too much emphasis on the filename extension (it's just the last few characters of the name): the contents of the file are more important.

Comment: Here we go: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_so.html Makes sense from the Apache perspective as it means that the same config files can be used on any OS.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows at least there is no technical requirement for any particular file extension. I imagine the same applies to Linux. File extensions simply provide a mechanism for the OS and the human operators to associate certain files with particular operations or applications.

Comment: In Windows there is a technical requirement for a particular file extension in several situations. This is not one of them, but the statement is a bit unclear.